# Introsort. Грамотная ли реализация?

Tags: c++, сортировка, qsort

По тестам в 9 раз медленнее обычного qsort'a на массиве из 100 000 элементов, заполненным псевдорандомом(на одном и том же). Вот [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/praserocking/5280579) я его взял.

Comment: Вы хотите код-ревью?

Comment: Это не мой код, просто хочу знать он верно реализован или нет? Уж слишком он медленно работает. В общем, да.

Comment: код написан как код на с, хотя выглядит как плюсовый. В коде есть несколько мест, где можно сильно красивее переписать. Работает медленно, потому что там много копирований массива, а обычный qsort написан нормальными программистами, поэтому и быстрее. Это нормально.

В Вашем вопросе есть опечатка. Исправьте.

Comment: `if(depth=0)`, сомневаюсь я что код работает так, как задумывалось

Comment: `if(depth=0)` -- Да, похоже ошибка, в вике неписано "Он использует быструю сортировку и переключается на пирамидальную сортировку, когда глубина рекурсии превысит некоторый заранее установленный уровень (например, **логарифм от числа сортируемых элементов**). " И переключения на insertion для небольших отрезков в qsort части я не вижу. Да и проверка issorted() при  каждом разделении выглядит сомнительно (если это действительно хочется проверять, то я бы нагрузил этой дополнительной функцией partition())

Comment: @Abyx, если вообще свое  не писать, то никогда не научишься делать хоть что-то нетривиальное (или даже мыслить об этом)

Comment: @Abyx, вот с этим полностью согласен, а особо раздражает, когда из гита такими "экзерсисами" помойку сделали.

Comment: Нет, с `if(depth=0)` я ошибся (**конечно, надо = заменить на ==**). Тут все нормально, т.е. когда в ходе рекурсии заходим слишком глубоко depth становится нулем и вызываем heapsort (как и задумано).

Answer (score 1):

Как это ни странно, проблема в проверке `isSorted`, если её убрать, то время выполнения `qsort` и данной сортировки становятся сравнимы.

Так же вероятнее всего опечатка - `if(depth=0)`, однако она почти не влияет.

Comment: На рандомных данных не влияет, поскольку heapsort не вызывается. А так, конечно, вместо `=` надо `==`